# How to alter return type of the <cmath> pow function?

Tags: binary, return-type, pow

New here, and to C++..

I have written some code to convert decimal numbers into binary. While doing this I was forced to write my own function to raise a base number to some exponent. I had originally tried to use the cmath pow function, but as this returns a double, it wouldn't work. (I was trying to divide an integer by a double when calculating my "remainder" variable.)

Is there a way to take cmath library functions such as pow and alter the return type ( in this case to int), thus saving the need to come up with my own function? Or perhaps I was wrong to specify "n" as an integer in the first place, and I should have just used the double data type everywhere?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int power(int a,int b){
    if(b==0){
        return 1.0;
    }
    else{
        return a*power(a,b-1);      
   }
  }

void Convert(int n){
vector<int>a(32);
int one_count=0;
int remainder;

for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
    remainder=(n/(power(2,i))%2);
    if(remainder==1){
        one_count++;
    }
    a[31-i]=remainder;
    if(n/power(2,i)==0){
        break;
    }
    }
    cout << "The 32 bit representation of " << n << " is "; 
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        cout << a[i];
    }
    cout << " and it has " << one_count << " set bits." << endl;
```

}

Comment: you could have cast your int to a double before doing the division. I.e. double remainder = (double)x / y;

Comment: -- Edit, you'd have to convert or cast the return type to an int, or alternatively, write a function that calculates integer-only powers. It returns a double in order to account for cases like: std::pow(2, 2.5);